# Get repeated column values only once through JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I wonder if does exist a way to select through JPA in particular JPQL from a table different column values just once. For example i have a table like that

```
ITEM1 10
ITEM2 30
ITEM1 25
ITEM2 11
ITEM3 56
ITEM3 9
```

I would select ITEM1 ITEM2  and ITEM3. I haven't found anything to achieve this in pratical and fast way.

Comment: you can read up on how to use 'unique'. The usage depends on your table constraints and the API you are using (JPQL/Criteria).

Comment: Or use `SELECT DISTINCT()` or `SELECT ... GROUP BY`.